# TYPO3 7.6 backend search (TCA searchFields) does not work on related table

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Following constellation:

- TYPO3 7.6.6
- own Extension

I have two simple tables:

- tx_exaibbrplus_domain_model_clients (clients)
- tx_exaibbrplus_domain_model_yearsclientsinstitutions (yci)

One "clients" with a column for a social security number (ex: 123.4567.675.432)). Another (yci) with a relation to clients.

I need the possibility to search the social security number on the second table (yci). On the classic list view I can see the clients social security number (see screenshot) but the list search does not work on the clients social security number.

[image: listing with social security number (related table) is displayed]

My TCA (most important parts) of the second table contains "clients" in searchFields.

```
return array(
'ctrl' => array(
    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:exaibbrplus/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_exaibbrplus_domain_model_yearsclientsinstitutions',
    'label' => 'year',
    'label_alt' => 'clients',
    'label_alt_force' => TRUE,
    'searchFields' => 'year, clients',
```

Using the live search to search a social security number works (and brings results of clients table).

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigations and exchange with TYPO3 gurus...  I led myself to the illusion this can be achieved because it was so easy to display the related data in the list. Meanwhile I also found a feature whish for this, see: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75017

In short: there is no solution for this with actual stock TYPO3.